# Determine Amount of Directories in a Directory

Tags: php

How would one go about efficiently determining the amount of directories in a directory in PHP?

For example, lets say I have this as a structure:

```
/Directory/ -->
... /Directory 1/
... /Directory 2/
... /Directory 3/
... File.txt
... Filed2.txt
```

Would be great to know that their are 3 Directories, so as not to include the current or files themselves.

Comment: Scan through the directory and use `is_dir()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$path = 'Directory';
echo ( count ( glob("$path/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR) ) );
```

Comment: Quick and easy to remember. However, will this count the directories in the directories themselves, or only go one step in from the main directory?

Comment: It should count the directories in the path given

Answer (score 2):

This code will do it:

```
$count = -2; // Subtract 2 for directories "." and ".."
$dh  = opendir('path/to/dir');
while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh)))
    if(is_dir($filename))
        $count++;
```

The reason for assigning `$count` the value `-2` is to account for the current directory and the parent directory.  This will count all directories including hidden ones. If you don't want hidden ones on a linux system simply check if the first character is a `.` using `false !== strpos($filename, '.')`, and initialize `$count` to `0` instead of `-2`.